# Extracting value from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arrayDif = array();
$arrayDif[] = array('employer' => $employer,
                    'comment' => $comment,
                    'value' => $resultValue);
```

Filling in from a loop.

Below is the array that I have filled up. I need to be able to find a match by the 'employer' and 'comment' and extract the value, so I can re-update this value.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employer] => Albury-Wodonga
            [comment] => allOtherMembers
            [value] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [employer] => Albury-Wodonga
            [comment] => associateMembers
            [value] => 1
        )
```

Comment: I deleted my entire answer now that I understand your question better. You need to learn to loop through an array. There are tons of tutorials out there for that. Better you learn that over just being shown. You need a `foreach()` loop.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping to just do one command to get the result.

Answer (score 2):

One command to extract and re-update the value, I suggest to use foreach loop

```html
<?php
    $arrayDif = array();

    $arrayDif[] = array('employer' => "AAA", 'comment' => "comment 1", 'value' => "1");
    $arrayDif[] = array('employer' => "BBB", 'comment' => "comment 2", 'value' => "2");
    $arrayDif[] = array('employer' => "CCC", 'comment' => "comment 3", 'value' => "3");
    
    // function for setting the value or returning the value
    // notice the $array here is a reference to the real array
    function func(&$array, $employer, $comment, $value = ''){
        // $v is also a reference
        foreach ($array as $k => &$v) {
         if($v['employer'] == $employer && $v['comment'] == $comment) {
             if(empty($value)) {
                 return $v['value'];
             } else {
                 $v['value'] = $value;
             }
         }
        }
        return "Not Found.";
    }
    
    //update
    func($arrayDif, 'AAA', 'comment 1', "123123");
    
    //search
    echo func($arrayDif, 'AAA', 'comment 1');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but here you go. I would use a function and simple loop.

```html
<?php 
    $arrayDif = array();

    $arrayDif[] = array(
                    array('employer' => "Albury-Wodonga", 'comment' => "allOtherMembers", 'value' => "1 star"),
                    array('employer' => "Employer2", 'comment' => "Good Job", 'value' => "2 stars"),
                    array('employer' => "Employer3", 'comment' => "Smart", 'value' => "3 stars")
                );
    
    // Function for searching the array for the matches and returning the value of the match.
    function SearchMe($array, $searchEmployer, $searchComment){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
            for($j = 0; $j < count($array[$i]); $j++){
                
                if(
                  $array[$i][$j]["employer"] == $searchEmployer &&
                  $array[$i][$j]["comment"] == $searchComment 
                  ){                    
                    return $array[$i][$j]["value"];
                }
            }   
        }
        return "No Match";
    }
    
    echo SearchMe($arrayDif, "Albury-Wodonga", "allOtherMembers");
?>
```

Comment: This is something close to what I had tried. Your solution has an 'Undefined offset: 0' and 1 and 2
It occurs on line: $array[$i][$j]["employer"]

Comment: Sorry to see you get that error. I am running the exact same code above on my page and it is working without errors.